# Make all identifiers more visible, types and modifiers less visible, in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

FWIW, I am using IntelliJ, but this could be solved by other code viewers/editors, instead.

What I want is a way to scroll through Java code, and make the actual freaking NAMES of things in definitions stand out, de-emphasizing all the other "important" stuff in front of the names, all the modifiers, mile-long type names and multiple mile long type names inside generic type angle brackets.

```
@EvenMoreComplicated @Pinky(extended=true) private static final volatile UltimateUtility<Blah,Yak,Freaking,Enough> theName(...
```

vs

```
/.../ theName... *the definition would still show here*
```

I just want a way to easily see the bloody names of classes, properties, methods and local variables when I am trying to read this sludge :-(

I'm NOT asking for the feature that highlights instances of a selected identifier.

I'm losing the forest in the trees.  It's distracting to have to look back and forth at the tree structure viewer, which doesn't show local variables (at least in Java, somewhat in JS)

Maybe I'm trying to solve the wrong problem?  Well, they pay me (and my coworkers) to do large portions of my work in Java, so that's the gig.

Comment: Perhaps consider reformatting with a rational set of formatting rules?

Comment: I seem to have ... "upset" at least 2 java programmers with my question.  But seriously, I want to see the bloody buried identifiers (names) which are being declared!  (usually in the middle of an initialization, as well)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not currently possible in IJ or any other IDE for that matter (please correct me if you know otherwise). There are a few tricks you can do, but none of them is an exact match of what you're looking for. Either way, you should be having each annotation on a separate line, so this does not really add any value for method annotated parameters.

Please note that the key bindings used below are for Windows and IJ 2016.2. You can check/change your own shortcuts from `File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap`.

1) ["collapse by default" settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-folding-2.html): go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Code folding` and select what you'd like to be folded by default:

[image: code folding settings]

1) custom folding regions ([blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/) & [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-folding.html#folding_predefined)): select a region and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

[image: collapse region]

2) collapse everything (custom region included. it seems): <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad -</kbd>

[image: collapse all]

Comment: Thanks for the custom folding tip.  Reformatting other people's code really isn't an option for me.  Even if I moved their annotations to another line (like mine are), that still leaves the (sometimes nested) generics wokka stew.

Comment: I have started breaking out my generic declarations as if the < and > chars were curly braces in K&R formatting, so I don't go blind :-)  Still can't make others not write 256 character lines with identifier names (vs types, etc) out at column 132.

Comment: Recent update: intelliJ has a plugin called "Varsity" which hides types of locals, showing var (or val) instead until you click on the placeholder.